# Custom Eslint rules in monorepo

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have a monorepo with a server and frontend. I want to incorporate a set of custom eslint rules into the frontend component of my repo. I cannot find a way to tell eslint that there are custom rules in a specific folder within my frontend directory. I don't want to create a new external repo and publish this in order to import the rules. So far I think the way to do what I want is to create a sub-package within the main repo (with its own package.json).

In my root package.json I have `"eslint-plugin-atlas": "file:./src/main/javascript/build/eslint",`

In my root .eslintrc I have `"plugin:atlas/recommended"`

In the directory specified in package.json, in an index.js, I have the below code;

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    rules: {
        'tsx-qualified-class-state-definition': {
            meta: {
                docs: {
                    description: 'A test rule',
                    category: 'Best Practices',
                    recommended: true,
                },
            },
            create: function(context) {
                console.log(context, 'THIS HAS BEEN HIT');
                return {};
            },
        },
    },
    configs: {
        recommended: {
            rules: {
                'tsx-qualified-class-state-definition': 'error',
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Obviously the above lint rule won't produce proper linting, but I'd expect to see the console statement to be output. When my intellij IDE trys to read the config I get the error;

```
Error: Failed to load config "plugin:atlas/recommended" to extend from.
Referenced from: F:\dev\workspace\lepton\src\main\javascript\build\.eslintrc.json
    at configMissingError (F:\dev\workspace\lepton\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\config-array-factory.js:233:9)
    at ConfigArrayFactory._loadExtendedPluginConfig (F:\dev\workspace\lepton\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\config-array-factory.js:674:31)
    at ConfigArrayFactory._loadExtends (F:\dev\workspace\lepton\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\config-array-factory.js:607:29)
    at ConfigArrayFactory._normalizeObjectConfigDataBody (F:\dev\workspace\lepton\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\config-array-factory.js:545:25)
    at _normalizeObjectConfigDataBody.next (<anonymous>)
    at ConfigArrayFactory._normalizeObjectConfigData (F:\dev\workspace\lepton\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\config-array-factory.js:491:20)
    at _normalizeObjectConfigData.next (<anonymous>)
    at createConfigArray (F:\dev\workspace\lepton\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\config-array-factory.js:307:25)
    at ConfigArrayFactory.loadFile (F:\dev\workspace\lepton\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\config-array-factory.js:382:16)
    at createCLIConfigArray (F:\dev\workspace\lepton\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cascading-config-array-factory.js:140:35)
```

When I run eslint I get errors `Definition for rule 'tsx-qualified-class-state-definition' was not found  tsx-qualified-class-state-definition`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution built into eslint, but this can be done with the following eslint plugin;

[npmjs.com/eslint-plugin-rulesdir](http://npmjs.com/eslint-plugin-rulesdir)

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this kind of an anti-pattern? I think you're supposed to have configs in each package directory.

```
/
 - package.json
   /packages
       /pkg-1
         - .eslintrc.json
       /pkg-2
         - .eslintrc.json
```

See [here](https://verdaccio.org/blog/2019/09/07/managing-multiples-projects-with-lerna-and-yarn-workspaces) for a bit more info, kind of a broader post, but should give you some direction.

Comment: I was dealing with a single javascript package of the frontend. The backend is written in Java - yes the monorepo has both java and javascript! I didn't want to introduce lerna for the sake of two packages, I'd rather have my frontend developed as a single package as I will only ever output a single bundle.